# How do you prove a CW complex is locally path connected

Tags: general-topology, cw-complexes, path-connected

I think this is done inductively on the skeletons but I can't work out the details.

Comment: They're not just locally path-connected, they're locally contractible.   There's a key theorem about CW-complexes, that the inclusion of any of any subcomplex into the entire CW-complex is a cofibration.  Look at that proof and the neighbourhoods constructed in that proof.  That should give you the idea for how to prove what you want to prove.

Comment: Please give full details in the question, not just the title. Also, what is a CW complex?

Comment: @Asaf What additional details do you want, exactly? And all definitions are easily googlable.

Comment: @Grigory: It's not that I complain about lack of definitions. I complain about bad formatting, while at it I was asking what is a CW complex.

Comment: @Asaf: First google hit: [CW complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex): A space obtained by gluing disks together. The topologist's preferred notion of a polyhedron. All reasonable (geometric) spaces are CW complexes. C: closure finite, W: weak topology. Inventor: J.H.C. Whitehead.

Comment: Have you looked at Hatcher's book?

Comment: Dear @RyanBudney I saw this problem in Lee's book where he haven't introduce the conception of contractible. Can you tell me how to prove it directly? Thank you!

Comment: I proved this very carefully here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448789/understanding-construction-of-open-nbds-in-cw-complexes/1462419#1462419

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following two general topology facts:

1. A disjoint union of locally path-connected spaces is locally path-connected.
2. A quotient of a locally path-connected space is locally path-connected (See [Lemma 2 in this post](https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/the-locally-path-connected-coreflection-iii/)).

Let $X_n$ be the n-skeleton of a CW-complex $X$. $X_0$ is obviously locally path-connected. Inductively, $X_n$ is the quotient of the disjoint union of $X_{n-1}$ and n-cells so $X_n$ is locally path-connected. Now $X=\bigcup_{n}X_n$ has the weak topology with respect to the subspaces $X_n$. Equivalently, $X$ has the quotient topology with respect to the map $\coprod_{n}X_n\to X$ defined in terms of the inclusions. Since $\coprod_{n}X_n$ is locally path-connected, so is $X$.

Comment: You also need finiteness, in terms of number of cells.  For example, consider the CW complex constructed starting with the unit square sitting in the first quadrant of the plane.  Now add horizontal lines between the points (0,1/2) & (1,1/2), and between (0,1/3) & (1,1/3), and between (0,1/4) & (1,1/4), etc.  Now the interior of the base of the square on the x-axis is not locally path connected.

Comment: That's not a CW-complex. By definition, a CW-complex has the weak topology with respect to it's cells.

Comment: You can also do this without induction on skeleta. Choosing $\chi_i : D_i \to X$ to be an indexed set of characteristic maps of the cells of $X$ (of all dimensions), it follows that $X$ has the quotient topology with respect to the disjoint union map $\chi : \sqcup_i D_i \to X$.

Comment: @PetraAxolotl The topologist's sine curve is connected and therefore _in particular_ not the disjoint union of two non-empty spaces.

Comment: @PetraAxolotl I think you're not quite reading the claim correctly: Disjoint union here is meant in the sense of coproduct. In other words, the topologist's sine curve $S$ is not of the form $S \cong A \sqcup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty topological spaces. Of course you can always decompose a space _internally_ into whatever nonempty sets you'd like.

Comment: @BenSteffan Got it! Thanks for the clarification.